# Limit sets and orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider  a  ﬁrst-order  autonomous  system  in  R1.   Suppose f (x) is  diﬀerentiable, f(0) = f(1) = 0,  and f(x) > 0 for x ∈ (0, 1).  Determine the orbit γ(x) and the limit sets ω±(x) if x ∈ [0, 1].

I have trouble understanding how to get an orbit or the omega limit sets. Hoping someone can explain with this question. Thanks

Comment: could you possibly play with some samples, e.g. a parabola opening down and a scaled sine curve to see what the orbit may look like and why?

Comment: I don't understand it enough o know what to draw.